# HTML/Bootstrap Table Sorting and Sort Direction Indicator

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to display and sort a table. I was wondering how/if I could implement a temporary arrow(or something) in each header in the table to indicate which direction it is being sorted.

Comment: Please provide the code you have so far so that we can use it to help you accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. For the header, add the following...

```
<table>
    <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Column 1 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></th>
             ...
         </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I assume you actually want the icon to sort the table, as well.

This is dynamic behavior, so you won't be able to do this in pure HTML/CSS: you will need to use JavaScript.  Here are the general steps that you would do to make this happen:

1. Store all of the table rows inside of a JavaScript variable
2. Inside the `<th>`, place another element, like a `<span>` or `<img>` that contains your arrow image.
3. Attach a click handler to the arrow, that sorts the array of table rows
4. After the array is sorted, use DOM API functions to remove the old table, create a new table, and then insert a new table in its place.  Bootstrap usually is used with jQuery, so you can look at some jQuery functions to remove the table, build a new one (by going through the rows), and then render the built table to the page, in place of the old one.

There are a variety of libraries that do this, but you can accomplish it more simply by doing it yourself.